# jQuery if div has CSS of left: 1% then do something

Tags: jquery, if-statement

Is it possible to add an if statement to jQuery so when you click an element a function only runs if another div has the CSS value of left: 1%?

Later on the CSS may change and I would need it so when you click an element the first function does not to not fire, but for a different one does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/sweG7/

Note that there is position:absolute for the element. Without that jquery always returns the value as 'auto'

Answer (score 6):

```
if ($('.className').css('left') == '1%')
    alert('do something');
```